# dtrace and linux perf tools not working in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, perf, dtrace, systemtap

I have a node.js application running on a aws ubuntu instance. I was trying to generate flamegraphs using `dtrace` and `linux perf tools` but none of them seem working.
these are steps I am following :

linux perf tools: https://www.carlhopf.com/blog/2016/09/11/nodejs-cpu-profiling-production/

dtrace: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/uncategorized/profiling-node-js/

I have added the `--prof / --perf_basic_prof_only_functions` while starting the app for linux perf tools commands.

The output I get from the dtrace stacks.out file is:

```
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  0 330511                        :tick-60s
```

Installed `dtrace` following this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/60940/how-do-i-install-dtrace

The output I get when I try to convert the output from linux perf commands to flamegraph is

```
ERROR: No stack counts found
```

I am not sure what's missing and why no stack trace was recorded. 
`node version: 8.4.0
ubuntu : 14.04`
I do see there is `Systemtap` option available and can use this command:

```
stap -s 32 -D MAXBACKTRACE=100 -D MAXSTRINGLEN=4096 -D MAXMAPENTRIES=10240 \
    -D MAXACTION=10000 -D STP_OVERLOAD_THRESHOLD=5000000000 --all-modules \
    -ve 'global s; probe timer.profile { s[backtrace()] <<< 1; } 
    probe end { foreach (i in s+) { print_stack(i);
    printf("\t%d\n", @count(s[i])); } } probe timer.s(60) { exit(); }' \
    > out.stap-stacks
```

but not sure how I can run that command using PID for the node app I am running. Is there any other way I can generate flame graphs in the ubuntu machine?

Comment: For the systemtap script, at least two ways to force it to focus on your particular process:   add  `-x $PID`  to the command line, or add an explicit    `if (pid() != $PID) next;`  statement at the top the timer.profile `{ ... }` block.